# reading file to check for same number of delimiters

Tags: python

I have created a method which reads a file line by line and checks if they all contain the same number of delimiters (see below code). The trouble with the solution is that it works on a line per line basis. Given that some of the files I am dealing with are gigabytes in size, this will take a while to process, is there a better solution which will 1) validate whether all lines contain the same number of delimiters 2) not cause any out of memory issues. Thanks in advance.

```
def isValid(fileName):
    with open(fileName,'rb') as infile:
        for lineNumber,line in enumerate(infile,1):
            count = line.count(',')
            if lineNumber > 1 and prevCount != count:
                # this line does not contain the same number of delimiters
                return False
            prevCount = count
    return True
```

Comment: Have you tried `freadline` or `fread()`?

Comment: In terms of memory, it is probably the best. Checking all lines at once implies that all lines are stored in memory I guess. While here only one line will be stored

Comment: You have to potentially process every line so there is no short cut around that. You are only storing a single line count at a time so memory is not going to be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use all instead and a generator expression:

```
with open(file_name) as your_file:
    start = your_file.readline().count(',') # initial count
    print all(i.count(',') == start for i in your_file)
```

Comment: thanks but if the file is 5 or 10 gb will this solution work?

Comment: It should, yes. The use of any and a generator reduces the amount of memory usage and time of execution.

Comment: No. lines = your_file.readlines() puts the whole file into memory ... not good.

Comment: That line should read `lines = your_file.readlines` without '(). This will make it a generator.

Comment: @user1016274 I'm talking about the passed generator in the any function.

Comment: You've changed the code in your answer faster than I could type. Your idea with the generator is valid, only the code was wrong.

Comment: Now, with the `all` operator, reading from the file will only stop when the file is exhausted, right? In the original code, reading stopped as soon as the outcome was clear. Which might save a lot of time.

Comment: Well, you'd have to check all of them, you can't make assumptions. All the lines could have 10 commas and the very last line could have 5. You can't truncate your calculations.

Comment: Of course you can - you can stop reading when you encounter the first line with different number of delimiters. Only the worst case will run to the very end (i.e. IsValid == True).

Comment: Well according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) it's already internalized as seen in the equivalent code.

Comment: if there is a failure, in one of the lines, would it be possible to get the line number?

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different approach (without code):
1. read the file as binary, and in chunks of, say, 64 KB
2. count the number of end-of-line tokens in the chunk
3. count the number of delimiters in the chunk but only up to the position of the last EOL token
4. if both number do not divide evenly, stop and return False
5. At EOF, return True

As you'd have to handle the 'overlap' between the last EOL token and the end of the chunk the logic is a bit more complicated than the 'brute-force' approach. But in dealing with GBs it might pay off.

Answer (score -1):

I just noticed that - if you would want to stick with simple logic - the original code can be deflated a bit:

```
def isValid(fileName):
with open(fileName,'r') as infile:
    count = infile.readline().count(',')
    for line in infile:
        if line.count(',') != count:
            return False
return True
```

There is no need to keep the previous line's count as one single difference will decide it. So keep only the delim count of the first line.
Then, the file needs to be opened as a text file ('r'), not as a binary.
Lastly, by prefetching the very first line just before the loop we can discard the call to `enumerate`.